# Read list of numbers in txt file and store to array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a list of integers, one number per line and would like to store each of these numbers in an integer array to use later in the program.

For example in java you would do something like this:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("Integers.txt");
int[] integers = new int [100];
int i=0;
while(input.hasNext())
{
   integers[i] = input.nextInt();
   i++;
}
input.close();
```

How would this be done in C?

Comment: as always, show some effort by posting what you have done in C, explaining were you're stuck. `open` and `scanf` are your friends...

Comment: Yeah I would like to know how to do it in C. I put an example in java.

Comment: @LihO if you read the OP carefully it was an example of what he is trying to do in java.

Comment: @TrialName Welcome to SO! Basic file I/O is a common subject covered by many online tutorials and hard-copy text books. Please do some research on your own and come back with specific questions about things you don't understand. Good luck with learning C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a go. You'll be much better off if you read the man pages for each of these functions (fopen(), scanf(), fclose()) and how to allocate arrays in C. You should also add error checking to this. For example, what happens if Integers.txt does not exist or you don't have permissions to read from it? What about if the text file contains more than 100 numbers?

```
    FILE *file = fopen("Integers.txt", "r");
    int integers[100];

    int i=0;
    int num;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0) {
        integers[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
```

Comment: I would rather go with `while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) == 1)` though.

Comment: @Fredrik OP knows Java. A huge barrier to C is just knowing what functions to call. Hopefully OP will read the man pages for those functions and learn how they work.

Comment: @LihO Yes, checking for it equal to `1` would be better.

Comment: Thanks. Worked prefect. Sorry I'm just starting to learn C. I know this was a simple problem, but I didn't know the syntax, something I need to learn. Any resources that could help?

Comment: @TrialName Read The C Programming Language by Dennis Richite (the guy that originally wrote C itself).

Comment: You're assuming each integer is only 1 digit.  This fails if any of the lines have integers larger than 9

Comment: @krb686 No, I am not assuming that and this works just fine for integers larger than 9. Have you compiled and run it yourself before downvoting?

Comment: @shanet Not your exact code, I ended up using fgets to read entire lines.

Comment: @krb686 Then why the downvote? What I posted is correct and your claim that it only works for single digit integers is not correct. `fscanf` with `%d` as an argument very clearly accounts for all valid integers.

Comment: @shanet Yeah sorry, I misread your answer. You need to edit it though for me to change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  int integers[100];
  int value;
  int i = -1; /* EDIT have i start at -1 :) */

  if ((fp = fopen ("Integers.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    return 1;

  while (!feof (fp) && fscanf (fp, "%d", &value) && i++ < 100 )
    integers[i] = value;

  fclose (fp);

  return 0;
}
```