# Return an array of numbers read from a file

Tags: c

I have an assignment in which I need to write a function what reads numbers from file to an array and returns that array(pointer at the first element).
I wrote a functions what reads from file to array but I have no idea how to return it.

```
void to_array(FILE* file, int bufsize){
char arr[bufsize][100];
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
int i = 0;
while(!feof(file)){
    fscanf(file, "%s", arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Read [**Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: please look up formatting for code. A C function return value type is defined by putting the type in front of the function name. eg - int mySuperFunction().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read list of numbers in txt file and store to array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802470/read-list-of-numbers-in-txt-file-and-store-to-array-in-c)

Comment: You can't return the address of a local variable (well, you *can* but using it is a bug).  So you'll need to figure something else out instead or returning `arr`. Either have the caller pass in the array or create it dynamically and return it. Also, why on earth is the array of `char` instead of `int` and what is the point of `bufsize`?

Comment: Usually the user's prerogative where they want the file pointer, that is, you don't need `fseek`. Look at the documentation. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fscanf.html

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%s", arr[i]);` will read a all characters up to the next *whitespace* (or EOF) whichever occurs first. You must either (1) dynamically allocate within your function for `arr` or (2) pass a pointer to a sufficiently allocated `arr` as a parameter. Then `while (fgets (arr[i], 100, file) { arr[i][strcspn(arr[i], "\r\n")] = 0; i++; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

> ```
> void to_array(FILE* file, int bufsize){
>   char arr[bufsize][100];
>   ...
> }
> ```

your array is local, if you return its address it will not be able to use it

One way it to allocate it in the head by *malloc*, an other is to receive that array in argument to fill it. Note it cannot be static without having a constant size

Do not use *feof* check the result of *fscanf*

You read numbers, so the array must be an array of numbers, let consider of *int*

Example where the function receives the file descriptor and a pointer to a variable which will contain the number of elements placed into the array, the function return the array allocated in the heap as you wanted

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * to_array(FILE * fp, size_t * sz)
{
  int * a = malloc(0); /* initially empty */
  int v;

  *sz = 0; /* initially no element */

  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &v) == 1) {
    a = realloc(a, (++*sz)*sizeof(int)); /* add an entry */
    a[*sz - 1] = v; /* set entry */
  }

  return a;
}

int main()
{
  size_t sz;
  int * a = to_array(stdin, &sz);

  /* check */
  for (size_t i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);

  /* free used memory */
  free(a);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo 11 22 33 | ./a.out
11
22
33
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ echo 11 22 33 | valgrind ./a.out
==10080== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10080== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10080== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10080== Command: ./a.out
==10080== 
11
22
33
==10080== 
==10080== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10080==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10080==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 5,144 bytes allocated
==10080== 
==10080== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10080== 
==10080== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10080== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

The function allocate an additional entry each time, it is possible to do by block of a given number of entries to not have to do that each time an entry has to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `#include <stdio.h>` when using it.

Usually the user's prerogative where they want the file pointer, that is, you don't need `fseek`.

One must accept the buffer size as well as the buffer, or one could use dynamic `realloc`, (more complicated error reporting and `free`.)

Use the return values to decide whether to continue, not `feof`. I think you have chosen the right input-reading function with `fscanf`; be sure to read the [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fscanf.html). Specifically, `%s` is almost certainly not what you want; perhaps `%d`?

`while` risks overflowing the buffer; if you have a fixed-size buffer, something like this:

```
size_t i;
for(i = 0; i < bufsize && scanf("%d", buf + i) == 1; i++);
```

There are several things that can happen, including:

- Stream (file) error. Use `ferror` to test.
- You didn't hit the end of the file, this is appropriate to test with `feof`; if `i == bufsize` the programme has no more space to fit the number; otherwise, it's an invalid number. These conditions are awkward to handle, but I suggest [errno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h).
- Success.

Perhaps one wants to return a boolean value for success?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use an array with *automatic storage duration*, you must declare the array in the calling function and pass a pointer to the array to your function. You can then fill the array in the function. However, you must also provide a way to return the number of strings read. Your choice of a `void` type for your function complicates this (slightly) as you would normally choose a meaningful return type such as `size_t` allowing you to return the number of strings read. That notwithstanding, you can pass a pointer to a `size_t` value and update the value at that address within your function thereby making the number of strings available back in the calling function.

A few notes:

```
/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define STRSZ  32       /* maximum string stize in array */
#define NSTR  100       /* maximum number of strings in array */
```

(*don't skimp on buffer size*) The longest word in the unabridged dictionary (non-medical) is 29-characters and the longest 64-bit number is 20-character (including sign), so for normal use a buffer size of `30` will suffice, `32` will account for any trailing punctuation mark. (if space isn't a consideration for the number of strings you need to read, double `STRSZ` to `64`) Adjust the number of strings and the maximum characters in each as needed.

Your function can then be written to take a *pointer to an array of char [32]*, e.g.

```
 void to_array (char (*arr)[STRSZ], FILE *fp, size_t *nstr)
{
    *nstr = 0;  /* initialize number of strings to zero */

    /* protect array bounds while reading each string from file */
    while (*nstr < NSTR && fscanf (fp, "%31s" , arr[*nstr]) != EOF)
        (*nstr)++;  /* increment number of strings */
}
```

(**note:** the use of the *field-width* modifier `"%31s"` to protect the bounds of each string when reading from the file, and the use of `*nstr < NSTR` to protect the array bounds for the number of strings read from the file)

In `main()`, you can simply declare a 2D array with *automatic storage duration* and a variable to keep track of the number of strings filled, e.g.

```
    char arr[NSTR][STRSZ] = {{0}};  /* array to hold strings (max 31 char) */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* number of strings read */
```

Now you can call your `to_array()` function as follows:

```
    to_array (arr, fp, &n);     /* read strings from file, n holds number */
```

Putting it altogether along with proper validation that your file is open for reading before your call to `to_array()`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define STRSZ  32       /* maximum string size */
#define NSTR  100       /* maximum number of strings in array */

void to_array (char (*arr)[STRSZ], FILE *fp, size_t *nstr)
{
    *nstr = 0;  /* initialize number of strings to zero */

    /* protect array bounds while reading each string from file */
    while (*nstr < NSTR && fscanf (fp, "%31s" , arr[*nstr]) != EOF)
        (*nstr)++;  /* increment number of strings */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char arr[NSTR][STRSZ] = {{0}};  /* array to hold strings (max 31 char) */
    size_t n = 0;                   /* number of strings read */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    to_array (arr, fp, &n);     /* read strings from file, n holds number */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  /* output each string in arr */
        printf ("arr[%2zu] : '%s'\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/10int_nl.txt
8572
-2213
6434
16330
3034
12346
4855
16985
11250
1495
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fscanffile ../dat/10int_nl.txt
arr[ 0] : '8572'
arr[ 1] : '-2213'
arr[ 2] : '6434'
arr[ 3] : '16330'
arr[ 4] : '3034'
arr[ 5] : '12346'
arr[ 6] : '4855'
arr[ 7] : '16985'
arr[ 8] : '11250'
arr[ 9] : '1495'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Consider using `fgets()` if you need to read a line-at-a-time.